# Finding the description of the device connected to /dev/input/eventX

Tags: c, event-handling

I have a program that is listening to a certain event file handle. Is there a file I can read to get details about the specific event's device that I am listening to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that (a) you're on Linux and (b) you have `sysfs` mounted (typically on `/sys`), you can look at `/sys/class/input/eventX`.  This will be a symlink into the device tree; this should provide you some device details.  For example:

```
$  readlink /sys/class/input/event4
../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.4/2-1.4:1.1/input/input4/event4
```

For USB devices, you could then probably mount a `usbfs` filesystem and check out the `devices` file for more information.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have access to the file descriptor or is this an external program? If this is your fd to the actual device, a list of ioctls provides you with most info you'll need. Have a look at print_device_info from evtest, it does exactly that:

http://cgit.freedesktop.org/evtest/tree/evtest.c#n753