# Device event handling with /dev/input/eventX and c/c++

Tags: c++, c, linux, events, device-driver

I need to detect device of certain type (e.g. mouse) and catch its events in linux with daemon.

Usage of `Xlib` seems useless because `Xlib` can only catch an event with window created by application but not all system events (but if I am wrong, please correct me).

One of solutions was using of `/dev/input/eventX` files (where `X` is number). In command line with `ls -l by-id` I can detect which event file handles certain device.

Further googling led me to [libevdev](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/libevdev/). It is actually wrapper around system calls (you even have to obtain file descriptor of event file manually before handling this file with libevdev) but it can also find out **types and codes** of events that this device can emit before these events are emitted. But I can't use it because there is some difficulties with embedding it onto destination computers.

So the question is: can I do this with C/C++ without parsing of `ls -l by-id` output? I mean can I detect type of device binded to certain `/dev/input/eventX` file or at least get types of events that it can emit with only system calls?

And if there any solutions for detecting device events in linux else?

Thanks in advance.

=======

**[UPD]:** Another solution in addition to one that given by @AlejandroDiaz in comments to this post (by the way, did not found how to paste reference to certain comment) without using `libevdev` is reading event bits with ioctl and parsing them like this:

```
int c_iHd = open("/dev/input/event0", O_RDONLY | O_NONBLOCK);
if(c_iHd == -1)
{
    exit(1);
}
unsigned long c_uEventBits;
ioctl(c_iHd, EVIOCGBIT(0, EV_MAX), &c_uEventBits);
int hasButtonsEvent = (c_uEventBits >> EV_KEY) & 1;
close(c_iHd);
```

Verbose solution is described in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10341349/finding-the-description-of-the-device-connected-to-dev-input-eventx?rq=1).

Comment: Yes, because 'ls' is written in C... if you looking to replace ls, look around 'getdirentries' function. Are you looking to replace ls, or are you looking for using the mouse? /dev/input/eventX and libevdev is probably the way to go.

Comment: Libevdev is certainly the solution, but there is no ability to embed it onto target computer.

Comment: @Toniy static linking?

Comment: Accidentally posted previous comment. It seems to be my fault that I wrote too much unnecessary information :) Usage of `ls` was just one of steps of problem exploration and I don't need to use it. Libevdev is certainly the solution, but there is no ability to embed it onto target computer (it is quite young project which is not presented in linux by default and in packet managers as `yum` yet), so I must use some standard solutions (like system calls or Xlib or something else) that are presented in linux by default.

Comment: @AlejandroDíaz, what do you mean?

Comment: @Toniy you could link against libevdev statically then you would only need to deploy your binary to the target system

Comment: @AlejandroDíaz, thanks, that is solution that I overlooked. I'll make it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The core of libevdev is relatively simple and not much more than a read() that reads in a set of struct input_event. Those are defined in linux/input.h and you can get type, code and value from those.

Most of what libevdev provides is type-safety so you can't screw up the ioctls and some of the corner cases of event handling (most of them to do with multitouch).

If your need is fairly simple and straightforward, writing the code directly will work just as well, especially if even static linking isn't an option. All you need then is open(), read() and ioctl().